# kendo ui paging on grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using a regular web application, not MVC, and want to use paging on my grid, but I don't see where the page count is supposed to get passed to my query.

This is my page code

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
transport: {
        read: {
            url: "TestWS.asmx/GetCIPCodes",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json"
        },  // end of read
        pageSize: 5,
        pageable: true,
        serverPaging: true
    },
    //pageable: true,
    schema: {
        data: function (data) {
            return data.d;
        },
    }, // end of schema
});  // end of dataSource

$("#pgrid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    height: 300,
    filterable: true,
    sortable: true,
    pageable: true,
    //pageSize: 5,
    //serverPaging: true,
    serverFiltering: true,
    serverSorting: true,
        columns: [{
            field: "CIPCode",
            title: "CIP Code",
            width: 100,
        }, {
            field: "CIP_Name",
            title: "CIP Name",
            width: 100
        }, {
            field: "FEDClusterName",
            Title: "FED Cluster",
            width: 100
        }]

}); // end of pgrid
```

And this is my web service query

```
Dim CIP = (From c In _db.tblCIPCodes _
Where c.cipactive = True AndAlso c.CIPCode < "99.0000"
Select c.CIPCode, c.CIP_Name, c.FEDClusterName).ToList()

    Return CIP.ToList
```

What is happening is I get a list of 50 records and all display without any pages showing.

Comment: The data is show, but without pagination? Or you cant see any data ?

Comment: Try removing pageable: true, serverPaging: true from your transport section, here's [example](http://dojo.telerik.com/OHoji)

Comment: ok so I removed the pageable from the transport definition and added the pagination to the grid, but it has not made a difference. I still see a list, and the page is set to 0 and the list is scrollable and shows (50) records like before